# Reversing a two-dimentional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So I am trying to take a 10x10 array with random number inputs and in a certain format, and then display the reversed version of it (position [0][0] will now be [9][9] and so on and so forth, but I'm getting a C6385 error at the part that's supposed to create the reversed array. (problematic part encased in \\)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROW = 10;
    const int COLUMN = 10;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array[ROW][COLUMN] = {};
    int transposed[ROW][COLUMN] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = rand() % 10;

        }
    }
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            int it = ROW - i;
            int jt = COLUMN - j;
            transposed[i][j] = array[it][jt];
        }
    }
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    cout << "     ORIGINAL" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            cout << "     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   8   10" << endl;
            cout << "   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+" << endl;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            if (((j > 0) && (j < 9)) && (i < 10))
            {
                cout << " | " << array[i][j];
            }
            else if (j == 9)
            {
                cout << " | " << array[i][j] << " |";
            }
            else if ((j == 0) && (i == 9))
            {
                cout << i + 1 << " | " << array[i][j];
            }
            else if ((j == 0) && (i < 9))
            {
                cout << i+1 << "  | " << array[i][j];
            }

        }
        cout << endl;
        if (i < 10)
        {
            cout << "   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "     Transposed" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            cout << "     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   8   10" << endl;
            cout << "   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+" << endl;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            if (((j > 0) && (j < 9)) && (i < 10))
            {
                cout << " | " << transposed[i][j];
            }
            else if (j == 9)
            {
                cout << " | " << transposed[i][j] << " |";
            }
            else if ((j == 0) && (i == 9))
            {
                cout << i + 1 << " | " << transposed[i][j];
            }
            else if ((j == 0) && (i < 9))
            {
                cout << i + 1 << "  | " << transposed[i][j];
            }

        }
        cout << endl;
        if (i < 10)
        {
            cout << "   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+" << endl;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You mean `position[0][0]` is now `position[9][9]`, right?  In a 10x10 matrix, there is no [10][10] position

Comment: Make it easy on yourself. Think through reversing a `2x2` and then a `3x3` and then apply the same logic to your `10x10`.

Comment: A two-dimensional array is layed out contiguously in memory.  Reversing one takes the same amount of code as reversing a one dimensional array.  You don't need all of those loops to do this.

Comment: Take advantage of the contiguous nature of a 2d array.  [Here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9781c1ff7c2709c8).  The only function that is used is `std::reverse`, which you can replace with your own reversal function.  The start of a 2d array is `&array[0][0]` and the last element is `&array[ROW-1][COLUMN-1]`.  If you just had a function, `reverse(int *start, int *end)`, it would work correctly for 1d arrays or 2d arrays, given you give it the starting address and ending address of the array.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't have error codes memorized. What is a "C6385" error? (In case I'm being too subtle: please edit your question to include the full error message.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problematic:

```
            int it = ROW - i;
            int jt = COLUMN - j;
```

When `i` is `0`, then `it` is `10`.  Same for `jt`  Remember `[0,0]` maps to `[9,9]` because arrays always start at an index of 0.  The last valid element in an `N` sized array is `[N-1]`, not `N`.

So when this line is executed:

```
        transposed[i][j] = array[it][jt];
```

Oops.  `transposed[0][0] = array[10][10]`.  That's not what you want.

Hence you want this:

```
            int it = ROW - i - 1;
            int jt = COLUMN - j - 1;
```

Hence, your code runs pretty well at that point:

```
     ORIGINAL
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   8   10
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1  | 6 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 6 | 5 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2  | 4 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 6 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3  | 4 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4  | 7 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 3 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5  | 8 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 9 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
6  | 6 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 8 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
7  | 6 | 2 | 3 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 6 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
8  | 6 | 9 | 5 | 8 | 0 | 9 | 8 | 9 | 3 | 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
9  | 5 | 5 | 0 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 8 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
10 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 4 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     Transposed
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   8   10
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1  | 4 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2  | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 8 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3  | 0 | 3 | 9 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 8 | 5 | 9 | 6 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4  | 6 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 7 | 6 | 9 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5  | 8 | 2 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 6 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
6  | 9 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 8 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
7  | 3 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 7 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
8  | 0 | 8 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 4 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
9  | 6 | 4 | 9 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 9 | 2 | 4 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
10 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 6 | 6 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

It compiled on me without error but there's a problem on values like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7HuJ.png)
I am using Clion v3.15 and c++ 14

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @serbie fixing your indexing problem, you can simplify the algorithm for reversing the array itself -- in-place without the need of a second array. With your current algorithm, you are not so much reversing an array as you are simply filling a second array with the elements of the first in reverse order. If you attempted to actually reverse `array` in-place, you would just end up swapping each element twice and end up with the same array as you started with. Additionally, an odd or even number of rows would provide different results.

For your annotated output, you would still need to output the array with the headings and row-numbers you like, but for the reversal itself, in-place, it can be reduced to, e.g.:

```
#define ROW  3
#define COL ROW

void rev2d (int (*a)[COL])
{
    /* loop rows increment from 0 while row < end row decrementing from ROW-1 */
    for (int i = 0, j = ROW-1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
        /* loop cols 0->COL-1 and COL-1->0 while i != j or col < endcol */
        for (int k = 0, l = COL-1; i != j ? k < COL : k < l; k++, l--) {
            /* swap element */
            int n = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = a[j][l];
            a[j][l] = n;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** you can modify the function to take the `row` and `col` values if you are not using constants)

The algorithm will work for `row` and `col` values greater or equal to `2` (you can add a check for an array of size `1x1` and issue a warning if desired, or just let things remain unchanged as it would be currently).

The handling of *odd / even* number of rows is done through the ternary used in the inner-loop conditional, e.g. `i != j ? k < COL : k < l` which reverses full rows unless there are an odd number of rows, and then when `i = j` it simply reverses to the middle-element

It provides the complete reversal of the array, e.g.:

**Example**

```
$ ./bin/revarr2da
original array:
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
  7  8  9

reversed array:
  9  8  7
  6  5  4
  3  2  1
```

Your algorithm is fine if you want to fill a separate array, if you are interested in swapping the values in place, this is just an additional way to approach it with